# Cannot load variables or mixins using inline-style-loader

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, sass, webpack, inline-styles

I would like to use `twitter-bootstrap` with `inline-styles`, in order to do so, I have setup:

```
{
   test: /\.scss$/,
   loaders: ['raw', 'inline-style', 'autoprefixer?' + autoprefixerOptions, 'sass']
}
```

I have installed `bootstrap-sass` and `radium` using npm. I wrote this code:

```
import normalize from 'radium-normalize'
import m from '../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_mixins.scss'
import v from '../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss'
import sc from '../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_scaffolding.scss'
import t from '../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_type.scss'
import buttons from '..//node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_buttons.scss'
```

I attempt to add these to the `Style` component provided by `radium` like this:

```
const baseRules = {...normalize, ...m, ...v, ...sc, ...type}
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Style rules={baseRules} />
    <HelloWorld />
  </div>
)
```

I get these errors informing me that variables and mixins were not defined:

```
 ERROR in ./~/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_scaffolding.scss
Module build failed: 
  @include box-sizing(border-box);
          ^
      No mixin named box-sizing

Backtrace:
    stdin:12
      in /home/vamsi/Do/webpack-npm-plugin/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_scaffolding.scss (line 12, column 12)
 @ ./src/index.js 21:19-107

ERROR in ./~/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_type.scss
Module build failed: 
  font-family: $headings-font-family;
              ^
      Undefined variable: "$headings-font-family".
      in /home/vamsi/Do/webpack-npm-plugin/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_type.scss (line 11, column 16)
 @ ./src/index.js 25:12-93

ERROR in ./~/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_buttons.scss
Module build failed: 
  font-weight: $btn-font-weight;
              ^
      Undefined variable: "$btn-font-weight".
      in /home/vamsi/Do/webpack-npm-plugin/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_buttons.scss (line 12, column 16)
 @ ./src/index.js 29:15-100
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you `@import` bootstrap into the scss file where you need the mixins. With isomorphic styles you never know what you entry point may be so it's not like you use it in one place and forget about it.

Try importing like this:

```
   @import "~/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins"
```

`~` character will tell webpack to look in `modulesDirectories` resolvers ([See more](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-modulesdirectories))

Comment: The inline style loader is the wrong thing to use, it converts the styles for use with dom elements, I would then have to convert it to javascript objects. I would like to understand how I can take less/sass from something like twitter bootstrap and compile it for use with radium. The radium-loader throws an error for me.